# Job Application education question

Tags: communication

I have 108 GPS credits invested into a MSW degree, and am currently not attending so that I cannot truly state that the degree is in progress. What can I say if I do intend to complete but do not have a set completion date.

Comment: Possibly "MSW [currently on hold]" ?

Comment: And check your spelling, nothing worse than poor spelling on an application.

Comment: What is GPS, what is MSW?

Comment: When I was working on my Masters I would list it like *"Masters of Science, Computer Science, John Hopkins University, expected 2005"*. It presumes you know about when you will finish the degree. In the interview(s) just mention you are still working on it so folks don't mis-parse it as you already have it.

Answer (score 1):

TBD = To Be Determined will probably do nicely.  If it matters they can always ask you why/when.

Comment: If I read TBD on a resume I would assume the degree was in progress, but it wasn't known, when the final course would be taken.  As somebody who struggled to get that one elective I wanted, it would seem reasonable to me, so more context should be provided.

Comment: True, but I'm guessing it's a very small box which would only have room for say eight characters or less, so there's not a lot of options here.  Unknown, no idea, none, ...  Again, if the employer cares enough about the answer, they'll probably say so.